# iPhone screen turns black randomly but still on

Tags: iphone, screen

My iPhone SE (2022)'s screen randomly turns black. It is occurring while the phone is idle and its frequency varying from twice a week to every third months.

While the screen is black, I can 'push' the home button so the phone is on. I can bring it back to life with a hard-reset.

I searched online but all solution was a factory reset. Apple support suggested bringing it to a service, but it would be for a payment. So these solutions I want to do last.

Is it an issue that known with this phone or do you have any suggestions?